# Do I need to sign my ClickOnce app in order to be able to execute it from other PCs?

Tags: deployment, clickonce, code-signing

Do I need to sign my ClickOnce app in order to be able to execute it from other PCs?

I'm trying to execute the app from another PCs and is not possible. I can't do it. Not even on my machine unless I create a test certificate with visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a VSTO application, yes.

For WinForms/WPF/Console, not necessarily. Are you deploying it to one PC and trying to install it? Where are you deploying it to? A file share or a webserver? What happens when you try to install it on the other machine?

What version of .NET are you targeting? It only works with .NET 3.5 SP-1 and .NET 4.

Comment: Actually It was a VSTO. Thanks :D

Comment: Well, that answered that question. Do you have a signing certificate of any kind other than the test certificate created in Visual Studio? VSTO is really picky about this, probably because of all the problems with office and viruses over the years.